# What is the output of multivariate LSTM model?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, rnn

I am currently trying to build an LSTM model by using multivariate inputs, but I don't understand what exact output I am predicting.

I am currently using 5 features in the data as input data:

```
X_data = data[['Time', 'Avg CPU Load', 'F1', 'F2', 'F3']]
```

My main goal is to predict 'Avg CPU load' by using the other features as input data, but I am not sure if I am doing that.

In these features, I have made 'Time' as an index in the data frame.
Then I have used 60 timesteps in the below code.

```
new_X_train=[]
new_Y_train=[]
for i in range(len(X_data)-timesteps-1):
    t=[]
    for j in range(0,timesteps):
        
        t.append(X_data[[(i+j)], :])
    new_X_train.append(t)
    new_Y_train.append(X_data[i+ timesteps,1])
```

The variables 'new_X_train' and 'new_Y_train' have the inputs data that have to be inserted into the model. Then I define my model which is.

```
sq = Sequential()
sq.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True,
           input_shape = (None, 4)))
sq.add(Dropout(0.2))

sq.add(LSTM(units = 100,return_sequences = True))
sq.add(Dropout(0.2))

sq.add(LSTM(units = 100,return_sequences = True))
sq.add(Dropout(0.2))

sq.add(LSTM(units = 100))
sq.add(Dropout(0.2))

sq.add(Dense(units=1)) # only one output

sq.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

sq.fit(new_X_train, new_Y_train, epochs = 5, batch_size = 20)
```

Once the model is trained, I load the test data and implement 60 timesteps. I.E: I do the same for what I have done for the training data, and then I use the `X_test` data to predict the values.

```
predicted = sq.predict(X_test)
```

Now I am not sure what output the above code is predicting, like what feature is it trying to predict?

And how to make my model predict the 'Avg CPU load' feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict "Avg CPU Load", your `y_train` should be only the "Avg CPU Load" column and your `x_train` should be the rest of the columns (you might skip the time column if all timestamps are equally spaced).

The network will then learn a function mapping rest of the columns to "Avg CPU Load" and it shall be predicting the same.

In the testing phase, you also have to follow the same structure for `x_test` (and `y_test` i.e. ground truth).

In this case, for RNN, you are right by generating each training sample as all columns over 60 timestamps. You can check if the prediction is indeed what you want by plotting against the ground truth. Although, I think you should predict all the columns (`new_y_train` is all columns instead of avg CPU load only) i.e. make the output dimension the same as the input dimension.

Make the network predict the whole thing and pick your column of interest for your consideration. This is probably the more natural way to do it.

Comment: I wanted to implement an LSTM time-series multivariate model, so if I want to predict "Avg CPU Load", then I put the "Avg CPU Load" in y_train and and the rest of the columns in x_train.

But what I read for time-series is that we need to use time-steps i.e add previous timestamp data into the train and test data by using this code...
~~~
new_X_train=[]
new_Y_train=[]
for i in range(len(X_data)-timesteps-1):
    t=[]
    for j in range(0,timesteps):

        t.append(X_data[[(i+j)], :])
    new_X_train.append(t)
    new_Y_train.append(X_data[i+ timesteps,1])
~~~

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now i understand your confusion.  I think you are doing the right thing. It should be predicting "Avg CPU Load". You can check that by plotting train and test "Avg CPU Load" against timestamps.  However, one possible way to make this thing more intuitive is to predict all features instead of one and then take the corresponding column of "Avg CPU Load" for output. I am editing the original answer to say that.